# Python regular expression to extract the parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I have the following unwieldy code to extract out 'ABC' and '(XYZ)' from a string 'ABC(XYZ)'

```
import re

test_str = 'ABC(XYZ)'
partone = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', test_str)
parttwo_temp = re.match('.*\((.+)\)', test_str)
parttwo = '(' + parttwo_temp.group(1) + ')'
```

I was wondering if someone can think of a better regular expression to split up the string. Thanks.

Comment: `[i for i in re.split(r'[()]', test_str) if i]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that actually won't work; it will give `ABC` `XYZ`, the desired result is `ABC` `(XYZ)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `re.findall`

```
>>> import re
>>> test_str = 'ABC(XYZ)'
>>> re.findall(r'\([^()]*\)|[^()]+', test_str)
['ABC', '(XYZ)']
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'(.*)(\([^()]*\))', test_str)[0]]
['ABC', '(XYZ)']
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the most general solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in re.split(r'(.*?)(\(.*?\))', test_str) if i]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of input data, we can replace the `(` with space+`(` and split by space:

```
>>> s = 'ABC(XYZ)'
>>> s.replace("(", " (").split()
['ABC', '(XYZ)']
```

This way we are *artificially creating a delimiter* before every opening parenthesis.